# Twitter Bootstrap Navigation Bar - Right Align Dropdown Menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Twitter Bootstrap (v2.1.1) with a PHP site. I'm generating the navigation bar dynamically in a php script as the navigation bar will have different content if the user is logged in or out of the site.

I would like to align the last dropdown menu to the right of the screen but haven't been able to so far. Here's a jsFiddle showing a simplified version:

http://jsfiddle.net/fmdataweb/AUgEA/

I would like the Menu 2 drop down to be right aligned. The code the for last dropdown is the same as for other dropdowns:

```
<li class="dropdown pull-right">
<a href="properties.php?type=showall" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu 2<b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="propertiesSearch.php">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

I've tried chaging it to:

```
<li class="dropdown pull-right">
```

but that makes no difference. Anyone know how to pull the dropdown menu to the right like you can with forms and `<p>` text?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You need to change the `.pull-right` class to `ul` element instead of `li`.

**HTML**

```html
<ul class="nav pull-right">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="properties.php?type=showall" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Menu 2
      <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="propertiesSearch.php">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

**Version 2.1.1**

I rewrote your code including only necessary JavaScript plugins (bootstrap-dropdown.js), the latest version of Twitter Bootstrap (2.1.1) and support for responsive design.

http://jsfiddle.net/caio/gvw7j/

If you see the responsive menu in the above link, you can see the "wide result" in this link:

http://jsfiddle.net/caio/gvw7j/embedded/result/

`.pull-right` is defined by:

```css
.pull-right {
  float: right !important;
}
```

---

**Version 3.1.1**

There were no changes in this class. You might see the [helpers classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats) section.

However, the documentation recommends using the class `.navbar-right` because it has some specific optimizations, unlike the `pull-right` class.

Comment: Thank you very much - couldn't see the wood for the trees for a while there. Works great.

Comment: Not at all. I forgot to include the `bootstrap-collapse.js` to work with responsive menu, the update: http://jsfiddle.net/YzPYe/1/.

Comment: navbar-right is not exactly the same in TB 3. When you make your screen smaller the menu will fill the entire width(the expected behavior IMO), using pull-right it won't

Comment: `navbar-right` doesn't work when screen size is smaller than 768px. So one should use `pull-right` for `xs` size screens. Check code: http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.css

Answer (score 18):

If you came here trying to right-align a regular bootstrap `.dropdown-menu` and **NOT** a `.nav`, and are using **Bootstrap 3**, the correct class to add is `.dropdown-menu-right`

Here's the [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns):

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
  ...
</ul>
```

Comment: @Archonic yes it does, but not on mobile (xs) screen sizes. Do you know a workaround for that?

Comment: Updated link to docs for 3.3: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#dropdowns-alignment

And the link to docs for 4.0: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment

Answer (score 14):

For those using **Bootstrap 3**, `.navbar-right` would do the trick.

For eg.,

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
.
.
</ul>
```

Answer (score 11):

Instead of pulling the `li` element to the left, simply contain that element which you wish to be right aligned within its own `ul` list and pull that instead like so:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="properties.php?type=showall" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu 2<b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="propertiesSearch.php">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>    
</ul>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AUgEA/1/